# Bug? JQuery UI Tabs remove parents inline style automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using a JQuery UI Tabs (1.8.6). Here is my HTML

```
  <div id='outer1' style="height:520;width:610;">
   <div id='outer2' style="height:520;width:610;">
    <div id="tabs">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
     </ul>
     <div id='tab1'>Tab1</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

And the tab is created by `$('#tabs').tabs();`

However, after the tab is created, I found that `outer1.style` and `outer2.style` have been removed like

```
  <div id='outer1'>
   <div id='outer2'>
    ... the tab
   </div>
  </div>
```

Is it a bug of JQuery? I just want to have a way to fix the width and height of the tab. I cannot use css class because the width and height is dynamically calculated by server side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after you do `$('#tabs').tabs();`, run the jquery code to apply [CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to those IDs.

```
 $('#tabs').tabs();

 $('#outer1, #outer2').css('height', '520px').css('width', '610px');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `!important` flag in your CSS...

For example:

```
width : 610px !important;
```

See this issue for similar fix:  [jQuery UI - Autocomplete generated inline style override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071991/jquery-ui-autocomplete-generated-inline-style-override)